# Use Spray Json to convert 2D sequence of Any into Json

Tags: json, scala, seq, spray-json

I am trying to understand Spray Json and very new to Scala. I have `Seq(Seq("abc", 123, false, null), Seq("def", 45, "1234", 'C'))` so a `Seq[Seq[Any]]`. I am not sure how to go about this and I cannot find any examples online.

```
case class SeqFormat(Seq[Seq[Any]]) => {
    // something that would convert to Seq[Seq[String]] 
    //which will would return a Json like this
    //[["abc", "123", "false", "null"],["def", "45", "1234", "C"]]
}
```

I tried

```
val someSeq = [["abc", "123", "false", "null"],["def", "45", "1234", "C"]]
val myObj = someSeq.toJson
// This gives me an error saying Any is not valid
```

I would appreciate any hints or snippets to help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an encoder such as:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit object AnyJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[Any] {

  def write(x: Any) =
    try {
      x match {
        case n: Int    => JsNumber(n)
        case s: String => JsString(s)
        case c: Char   => JsString(c.toString)
        case _         => JsString("null")
      }
    } catch {
      case _: NullPointerException => JsString("null")
    }

  def read(value: JsValue) = ???
}
```

Which you can use as follow:

```
val input = Seq(Seq("abc", 123, false, null), Seq("def", 45, "1234", 'C'))
println(input.toJson)
```

In order to get:

```
[["abc",123,"null","null"],["def",45,"1234","C"]]
```

---

This is an adapted version of this post: [Serialize Map[String, Any] with spray json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916923/9297144)

Notice the NullPointerException handling for the `null` case.

Comment: This does not seem to work with `val input = Seq(Seq("abc", "123", "false","null)", Seq(1,2,3,4,5))
println(input.toJson)`  i.e. when each of the set has the same type of variables. It displays an error saying Cannot find jsonWriter or jsonFormat type class for Seq[Seq[AnyVal]]! Any suggestions on how to fix that

Comment: @ben What's your error? Shouldn't it be `val input = Seq(Seq("abc", "123", "false","null"), Seq(1,2,3,4,5))`?

Comment: i am running the code on intellij and it says "Connot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for List[Seq[AnyVal]] && not enough arguments for method toJson: (implicit writer: spray.json.JsonWriter[List[Seq[AnyVal]]])spray.json.JsValue." I tried to change the Any to AnyVal but then my other test values gives me error says expected:Any found:AnyVal

Comment: I'm using this version of json spray `"io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.3"`. Did you include the imports?: `import spray.json._` and `import DefaultJsonProtocol._`

Comment: yeah I am using the same `libraryDependencies += "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.3"`

Comment: Is the `AnyJsonFormat` in the same class/object as the call to `println(input.toJson)`?

Comment: Yeah they are in the same object. Maybe int's the intellij, lemme try running it on terminal directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166996/discussion-between-xavier-guihot-and-ben).